# In the history of sports

Tags: knowledge, sports

I received this riddle and I don't have any other hints , can you solve it ?

What does the following number represent in the history of sports?

> 26533500

Comment: still no hint ?

Comment: @Lordofdark I do not have any hints :/

Comment: In what country was this asked - it might help narrow down the sport.

Comment: @KenY-N Lebanon

Answer (score 1):

Probably the date could be (considering 26533500 as a timestamp format of a date): Wed, 04 Nov 1970 02:25:00 GMT but there's not in the history of sport that I remember. Someone reminds something important in this date?

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

> 26:53.3500 looks like the time needed to run the 10 km race (for a professional), but I wasn't able to find someone that did this. It's not the record or the first one to go under 27 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As Francesco suggested, if `26533500` is a timestamp, we get 4th of November 1970.

I've checked [this website](http://takemeback.to/04-November-1970#.VxYeS3ErJD8) and found this in terms of sport:

> *Famous People Born:*
>
> *Corey Schwab: North Battleford, Saskatchewan -- NHL goalie (New Jersey Devils)*
>
> *Tim DeBoom: American triathlete*